# How can I revert my last choice on terminal if it shows > symbol?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, terminal

I'll be glad if someone can fix the title to be more appropriate since I'm pretty new to terminal.

I have an issue with terminal. Once I execute a command, if it goes to the next line, I can't close it or revert it. I assume it starts the executable or asks for more parameters using >

For example:

```
//Windows Machine
vagrant up

    //Vagrant Instance Unix Machine
    $ git
    >
    >
    >
    > ... it goes on like this, I can't close > so I can't execute other commands
```

The only solution on fixing is restarting the terminal (which means I need to restart Vagrant instance)

It happens on some commands only - not all, so I don't know what makes a difference.

For example, executing `composer`, I get information about Composer and terminal goes back to main state. However, if I execute things like `php`, `git`, `mysql`, `>` symbol appears and I can't return from there.

So, two basic questions;

1. What causes this?
2. How can I terminate the current command to go back main state?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ps. I use both windows terminal and unix terminal and this issue happens on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'll see a `>` prompt if you've entered a command that's syntactically incomplete, for example if there's a unterminated string literal:

```
$ echo 'hello
> '
hello

$
```

It means that the shell is waiting for you to type the rest of the command, or at least enough of it to make for something that's not a syntax error.

In this example, the default prompt, `$PS1`, is `'$ '`, and the secondary prompt, `$PS2`, is `'> '`. Read the documentation for your shell ([probably bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html)) for more information.

You can cancel the current command and get back to your primary prompt for a new command by typing <kbd>Control-C</kbd>.

This is all about the behavior of your *shell*; it has nothing to do with your *terminal* (almost certainly a terminal *emulator*), which merely provides a GUI for your shell to run in.

Comment: Thanks alot! One more thing, what if it doesn't show `>` at all and just goes to next line? For example `php` does it.

Comment: That means the `php` command is waiting for input, presumably PHP code which it will execute. Use Control-C to kill it, or Control-D to indicate an end-of-file condition (the latter will cause the PHP command to execute with empty input). The `git` command with no arguments should show a usage message and then return you to your primary prompt; did it really behave the way you describe? Are you sure `git` is *exactly* what you typed?

Comment: Okay, thank you. Going to mark this as the answer in a minute. Edit: No, I accidently typed something else. `git` shows basic documentation and works normally.